# Variable-length negative look-behind for replacing list delimiters and the string end

Tags: r, regex, negative-lookbehind

I wish to insert an index after values that miss an index within a string of delimited values, including the last one.

```
s <- "Dee, DP(Dee, D. P.)[1];Uppala, SM(Uppala, S. M.);Simmons, AJ(Simmons, A. J.);Kobayashi, S(Kobayashi, S.)[2];Andrae, U(Andrae, U.)"
gsub("(?<!\\[\\d\\])(;|$)", "\\[0\\]\\2", s, perl=TRUE)
```

This code gives me missing delimiters:

```
"Dee, DP(Dee, D. P.)[1];Uppala, SM(Uppala, S. M.)[0]Simmons, AJ(Simmons, A. J.)[0]Kobayashi, S(Kobayashi, S.)[2];Andrae, U(Andrae, U.)[0]"
```

The code similarly handles the case where the last value already has an index:

```
s <- "Dee, DP(Dee, D. P.)[1];Uppala, SM(Uppala, S. M.);Simmons, AJ(Simmons, A. J.);Kobayashi, S(Kobayashi, S.)[2];Andrae, U(Andrae, U.)[3]"
```

Giving, this time (delimiters still missing):

```
"Dee, DP(Dee, D. P.)[1];Uppala, SM(Uppala, S. M.)[0]Simmons, AJ(Simmons, A. J.)[0]Kobayashi, S(Kobayashi, S.)[2];Andrae, U(Andrae, U.)[3]"
```

I need the missing delimiters back, e.g. in the first case:

```
"Dee, DP(Dee, D. P.)[1];Uppala, SM(Uppala, S. M.)[0];Simmons, AJ(Simmons, A. J.)[0];Kobayashi, S(Kobayashi, S.)[2];Andrae, U(Andrae, U.)[0]"
```

Additionally, I would like the code also to handle indices of more than one digit, i.e. 10, 100, etc. (variable length), e.g.:

```
s <- "Dee, DP(Dee, D. P.)[10];Uppala, SM(Uppala, S. M.);Simmons, AJ(Simmons, A. J.);Kobayashi, S(Kobayashi, S.)[2];Andrae, U(Andrae, U.)"
```

or

```
s <- "Dee, DP(Dee, D. P.)[10];Uppala, SM(Uppala, S. M.);Simmons, AJ(Simmons, A. J.);Kobayashi, S(Kobayashi, S.)[2];Andrae, U(Andrae, U.)[3]"
```

Comment: Your replacement pattern is off, you only have 1 capturing group, so you must use `\\1`, not `\\2`

Comment: Fantastic! I thought each set of parentheses represents a group. That leaves only the variable length aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your replacement pattern, `\2` refers to a non-existing Group #2. `(?<!...)` is a negative lookbehind and unlike capturing groups does not force a regex engine to  allocate any special memory buffer for its matched value.

You must use `\1`, not `\2`.

To solve the variable width pattern in the lookbehind, you may use a 2-step approach using a PCRE pattern with SKIP-FAIL verbs:

```
s <- gsub("\\[\\d+];(*SKIP)(*F)|(;)", "[0]\\1", s, perl=TRUE)
sub("(?s)^(?!.*\\[\\d+]$)(.*)", "\\1[0]", s, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/PRnoFU/3) / [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/PRnoFU/4) and the [R demo online](https://rextester.com/YWUVBS16043)

**Pattern #1 details**

- `\[\d+];(*SKIP)(*F)` - `[`, 1+ digits, `]` and then `;`; `(*SKIP)(*F)` discards this matched text from the overall match memory buffer and goes on to search for the regex pattern from the location where it failed
- `|` - or
- `(;)` - Group 1 (`\1` in the replacement pattern): a `;` char.

**Pattern #2**

- `(?s)` - turns the dotall mode so that `.` could match any char as in TRE regex (used by `sub` without `perl=TRUE`)
- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*\[\d+]$)` - a negative lookahead that make sure there is no `[`, 1+ digits and `]` at the end of string
- `(.*)`  - all the string is captured in Group 1.

Or, if you can use `stringr` and you know the number of digits is fewer than some value, say, 100, you may leverage this **constrained-width lookbehind** ICU library feature:

```
stringr::str_replace_all(s, "(?<!\\[\\d{1,100}])(;|$)", "[0]\\1")
```

Here, `(?<!\[\d{1,100}])` matches a location in string that is not immediately preceded with `[`, 1 to 100 digits, and then `]`.

Comment: Thank you! However, a minor quibble is that this code adds `[0]` to the last value even after an existing index.

Comment: @syre Yeah, that is a culprit due to the fact `$` is a zero-width assertion and the end position is tested twice here.

Comment: @syre I h ave a two step workaround, see [this R demo](https://rextester.com/TALI70247).

Comment: @syre If you can use `stringr` **and** you know the number of digits is fewer than some value, say, 100, you may use `stringr::str_replace_all(s, "(?<!\\[\\d{1,100}])(;|$)", "[0]\\1")`

Comment: The above is my solution, but I'll just mark the whole thing as the solution. Thanks again!

Comment: @Wiktor_Stribiżew How come escape characters \\ are not needed before the closing bracket in `(?<!\\[\\d{1,100}])`?

Comment: @syre `]` outside a character class is not a special regex metacharacter. `]` must only be escaped in an MSVC C++ regex ECMAScript flavor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208696/discussion-between-syre-and-wiktor-stribizew).